# How to call a function inside of a different function in vPython

Tags: function, while-loop, call, vpython

UPDATE: Ignore the top question. I figured it out (thanks to gilch). The only thing I need to know now is the second question below...How to call a separate function inside of another function.

When the while statement is finished and I reset, I can no longer move the ball because the while loop won't re-initiate, so I can't re-raise the ball to fall again. I have to completely restart the code. I'm a beginner with vpython (doing this for physics class), and I can't find a way to re-initiate the while loop (or however else to fix it).

I'm pretty sure that it is because the while loop ends and then when the position and velocity of the ball resets, the while loop won't re-initiate, so I can't move the ball, but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Code:

```
GlowScript 2.7 VPython
#Start without running
running = False
#when "Run" is initiated
def Run(b):
    #Bring in running variable from outside
    global running
    #When Run/Pause Button is pressed, switch between running and pausing the program
    running = not running
    #When run button is pressed, change text to "Pause"
    if running: bbutton.text = "Pause"
    #When pause button is pressed, change text to "Run"
    else: bbutton.text = "Run"

#Create Run Button above program
bbutton = button(text="Run", pos=scene.title_anchor, bind=Run)

#When "Reset" is initiated
def Reset(c):
    #Bring in t and ball variables from outside
    global t, ball
    #Set back to time = 0 (when reset)
    t = 0
    #Reset ball's position to initial position (when reset)
    ball.pos = vec(0,2,0)
    #resets ball's velocity to initial velocity (when reset)
    ball.vel = vec(0,0,0)

#Create reset button above program
cbutton = button(text="Reset", pos=scene.title_anchor, bind=Reset)

#Create ground
ground = box(pos=vec(0,0,0), size=vec(10,0.2,10))
#Create ball
ball = sphere(pos=vec(0,2,0), radius=0.4, color=color.yellow)
#Initial Velocity
ball.vel = vec(0,0,0)
#Acceleration (free-falling)
g = -9.8
#Initial Time
t = 0
#Time increase per frame
deltat = 0.01

#Turns "drag" condition to false to begin
drag = False
#Initial mouse position
R = vec(0,0,0)
#When you click
scene.bind("mousedown", def():
    #Bring in drag variable from outside
    global drag
    #Set drag to true on mouseclick
    drag = True

    #When you release click
    scene.bind("mouseup", def():
        #Bring in drag variable from outside
        global drag
        #Set drag to false when you release click
        drag = False
    )
)

#While True (the program is running) and the ball is higher than slightly under the ground
#If the second condition is not there, the ball will continually go down through the ground forever
#The second condition stops the ball once it begins going underneath the platform, so it looks normal

while True and ball.pos.y > ground.pos.y + 0.48:
    #Slow down program
    rate(100)
    #When the drag condition is true (When mouse is clicked on ball)...
    if drag:
        #Set R to position of mouse
        R = scene.mouse.pos
        #Set ball position to R (position of mouse) -- allows the ball to be     dragged (changes ball position)
        ball.pos = R
    #When the program is running (run button is pressed)...
    if running:
        #Update ball velocity
        #   v      =     v0     + a (change in time)
        ball.vel.y = ball.vel.y + g*deltat
        #Update position velocity
        #   x    =    x0    +    v    *(change in time)
        ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.vel*deltat
        #When the ball hits the surface of the ground...
        if (ball.pos.y <= ground.pos.y + 0.5):
            #Change the sign of the velocity (to go back up)
            ball.vel.y = -ball.vel.y
        if (ball.pos.y < ground.pos.y +0.48):
            break
        #Update time
        t = t + deltat
```

UPDATE: I put the while loop in function Initiate, but don't know how to add the Initiate function into the Reset function...

New Code (Only including related code):
    #OTHER CODE

```
def Reset(c):
    #Bring in t and ball variables from outside
    global t, ball
    #Set back to time = 0 (when reset)
    t = 0
    #Reset ball's position to initial position (when reset)
    ball.pos = vec(0,2,0)
    #resets ball's velocity to initial velocity (when reset)
    ball.vel = vec(0,0,0)

    #Initiate() -- HOW DO I RUN INITIATE INSIDE THE RESET FUNCTION**

#OTHER CODE

Initiate()    

def Initiate():
    global ground, ball, g, t, deltat, drag, R

    while True and ball.pos.y > ground.pos.y + 0.48:
        #Slow down program
        rate(100)
        #When the drag condition is true (When mouse is clicked on ball)...
        if drag:
            #Set R to position of mouse
            R = scene.mouse.pos
            #Set ball position to R (position of mouse) -- allows the ball to be dragged (changes ball position)
            ball.pos = R
        #When the program is running (run button is pressed)...
        if running:
            #Update ball velocity
            #   v      =     v0     + a (change in time)
            ball.vel.y = ball.vel.y + g*deltat
            #Update position velocity
            #   x    =    x0    +    v    *(change in time)
            ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.vel*deltat
            #When the ball hits the surface of the ground...
            if (ball.pos.y <= ground.pos.y + 0.5):
                #Change the sign of the velocity (to go back up)
                ball.vel.y = -ball.vel.y
            if (ball.pos.y < ground.pos.y +0.48):
                break
            #Update time
            t = t + deltat
```

Comment: Try making a mvce https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that. I kept that in mind for the second part of my question.

Comment: I usually point Python beginners to *A Byte of Python*, a free online book at the beginner level. https://python.swaroopch.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the while loop inside a function def, and starting it by calling the function. Then you can call the function again to re-start the loop.

Comment: I did that, gilch. However, I don't know how to take the initiate function and put it inside of the Reset function. I'm a beginner to python. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Initiate()` should probably work. If you tried that, what was the error?

Comment: It gives the error:
Error: error streamlining source: : Function contains async calls but does not have _ parameter:
undefined at line 89 STACK: Error: : Function contains asynch calls but does not have _
parameter: undefined at line 89 at _dolt

Comment: And then it gives a bunch of urls:
(http://sandbox.glowscript.org/package/RScompiler.2.7.min.js:1:1223258) at _propogate is one of them ---- there are different numbers at the end of each url. I have to manually type this in, so I don't really want to type the other ones unless absolutely necessary

Comment: That error makes no sense. Try putting the `Initiate()` after the `def Initiate` function.

Comment: I don't think the initial initiate when the program first starts is the problem. It is the one that I am putting inside of the def Reset(c)...it works without that, but once I add it in, I get that weird error. --- Do I have to bring in the Initiate function into the Reset function like I did with the t and ball variable? Is that possible? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Python actually does allow you to put function def's inside function def's. You could also declare the function name global first. I'm not that familiar with GlowScript, but your code shouldn't make that error by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Go to vpython.org and click on the link to the vpython forum  or the glowscript forum and ask your question there.